# How to connect SCA-2 to SATA?

Tags: sata

I have SCA-2 hard drive with connector like this:

http://www.ivoryegg.com/imagesNew/150000/154608--659238-7378.jpg

It's possible to connect it to motherboard with SATA?

Thanks!

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: He could add a SCSI card, and either a SCA backplane or a SCSI/SCA Adapter... Nothing to do with  SATA, but it could all be added.

Answer (score 2):

Not a hope.  Given that all those old SCA drives are going to have bugger-all capacity, just buy a SATA hard drive.  You could probably find someone locally who'll give one to you, if you can't afford to buy one.

Comment: I wanted to connect it to my PC, so it will run faster (like half-SSD) and its bigger (450GB 15K).

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

SCA is SCSI.

Alltough the software-protocols are nearly identical (SATA uses an extended SCSI command set) the electrical characteristics are completely different.

SCSI is basically parallel while SATA is serial. There ar eadapters out there but they are more expensive tahn a new SATA drive

Comment: Do you have an example for adapter? I don't know what to look.. Thanks!

Comment: Here's one that goes the other way: http://www.addonics.com/products/adsalvd160.php -- $129.  And that's the far, *far* more popular way to go, allowing cheap, modern drives to be used in older chassis that can't be upgraded.  Going the other way is going to be significantly less popular (and hence more expensive).

Comment: Yes, it's really high price. I have this HDD: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Seagate-ST3450856FC-Cheetah-15K-450GB-Fiber-Channel-Hard-Drive-17P9928-17P9907-/170738310884?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27c0cbdee4#ht_3928wt_1110 - Do you think it worth it? I want to install it to enjoy speed (Windows 7) and storage. SSD are too expensive.

Comment: "SATA uses an extended SCSI command set" <-- No, SATA uses the ATA command set, which isn't really close at all to the SCSI command set. SCSI commands can be tunneled through ATA, many CD-ROMS (et al) support this as ATAPI, but that's not the same. Also most SAS devices support STP (SATA Tunnel Protocol), but again, not the same.

Comment: Chris - so there isn't a solution?